# Is my variable considered okay to use in k-means clustering with Euclidean distance?

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, euclidean

I was wondering if I can use regular `kmeans()` in R with my variable "number of drug prescriptions" which equals a number between 1-25. From what I've read k-means only works with continuous variables. What would my variable be described as? From definitions on google I'd say categorical ordinal, but it is a numeric variable so I am a bit confused.

Comment: The bigger problem will be that the variable likely is quite *skewed* and that tends to harm kmeans.